# How to print a JS flag as a simple link in full node view?

Tags: theming, flags

I have two flags which are set up as JS toggle in their settings.  That's how they appear in teasers.
But in my full view of the node inside the block I want them to print as a normal link (no JS).
How can I do that?

So far I have this:

```
<?php
//If in single node page
if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ! arg(2) ) {
global $user;
if ($user->uid == $node->uid) print flag_create_link('FLAGNAME', $node->nid);
}
?>
```

But it returns the JS toggle flag,rather than a simple link. Can you help?